# wget not following links with mirror

Tags: wget

I'm trying to semi mirror a site. What I want is to download all of the MP3s and make sure I'm not redownloading those that I already have (hence the "mirror" part). I've typed in the following:

```
wget -m -nd -e robots=off --random-wait -A "*.mp3" -P FOLDER http://www.example.com/
```

And it downloads all the MP3s on the Current Page. It never follows the links to the "Next Page" or the likes. I've replaced the `-m` with `-N -c -r` without success. What other options can I use?

Comment: You want `no clobber` ... `-nc`

Comment: @Zak `wget -nd -e robots=off -r --random-wait -A "*.mp3" -c -nc -P FOLDER http://www.example.com/` did not traverse the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wget ‐‐execute robots=off ‐‐recursive ‐‐accept mp3,MP3 --random-wait ‐‐no-parent ‐‐continue ‐‐no-clobber //site.com/
```

Comment: Ari, can you add a brief explanation of how this solves the issue or what the op had missed?

Comment: `Resolving ‐‐execute (xn--execute-406ca)... failed: Name or service not known.` `Resolving robots=off (robots=off)... failed: Name or service not known.` `Resolving ‐‐recursive (xn--recursive-u79da)... failed: Name or service not known.`.... I think there may be a problem with `--long-name-switches` here...